# React Native App Auth keep prompting "User cancelled flow" when authorize

Tags: react-native, appauth

I am using the Example code of react-native-app-auth.
It keeps prompting "Failed to log in - User cancelled flow" after I clicked the Authorize button.
The provider is Okta and the configuration should be fine because it worked previously.
I'm not sure it's my code problem or the server side.

My Code:

```
    const configs = {
         okta: {
           issuer: 'https://myid.okta.com/oauth2/default',
           clientId: 'myidabcdefg',
           redirectUrl: 'com.okta.myid:/callback',
           additionalParameters: {},
           scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'offline_access'],
         }
    
    };

    const handleAuthorize = useCallback(
            async provider => {
                try {
                    const config = configs[provider];
                    const newAuthState = await authorize({
                    ...config,
                    connectionTimeoutSeconds: 5,
                    });
    
                    setAuthState({
                    hasLoggedInOnce: true,
                    provider: provider,
                    ...newAuthState
                    });
                    
                } catch (error) {
                    Alert.alert('Failed to log in', error.message);
                }
            },
            [authState]
        );
```

appAuthRedirectScheme in AndroidManifest.xml

```
    manifestPlaceholders = [
       appAuthRedirectScheme: 'com.okta.myid'               
    ]
```

[image]

Any idea?